# Launch screen Tab Bar unwanted space below

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

I have Tab Bar control in my LaunchScreen storyboard. There is unwanted space below it. (You can see the blue below it)

How can I make the Tab Bar expand down to cover that extra blue space?
[image]

I have the following constraints added:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Bottom of the Tabbar is aligned with `Safe Area Layout`

[image]

To solve this, follow the below screenshots

Select the bottom as view (Default Selected is Safe Area = 0 and view = 34). Make the view 0.[image]

Hit the "Add Constraint". Done!

[image]

Comment: I have added the Tab Bar.bottom = Safe Area.bottom constraint and I still have the same result as before. (See the new screenshot on my post)

Comment: remove the tab Bar.bottom = safe area bottom constraint. Then add according to my process

Comment: when I applied your process the tab bar gray area moved down (covering the blue), however, the icons for docs, prices, etc stayed above, so now they are outside of the tab bar.